# Riesz representation theorem finite dimnesional case

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics, riesz-representation-theorem

[image]

*I am taking a Quantum Mechanics course not a Functional Analysis course so I have only had a very basic introduction to Hilbert Spaces.*

I don't understand where the if and only if statement arises in the above theorem. How can I rewrite it so that the writing underneath the theorem makes sense?

Comment: The theorem says "all linear functionals can be represented in the form..." This can be restated as "$F$ is a linear functional on $H$ iff $F$ has the form..."

Comment: Is it definitely '$F$ is a linear functional on $H$' or is it instead '$F$ is a linear functional on $H'$'

Comment: I think I should have said "$F$ is a continuous linear functional on $H$ iff $F$ has the form...".  That would be equivalent to saying "$F \in H'$ iff $F$ has the form..."  ($H'$ is the set of all continuous linear functionals on $H$.)

Comment: Why does 'all' equate to iff, I understand why it means only if but not the other way round.

Comment: Actually, now that you put it that way,  I can see how "all" here would mean "only if" rather than "if and only if".  Just because all continuous linear functionals have this form, doesn't necessarily imply that everything of this form is a continuous linear functional.  I see what you mean. But, it's obvious that anything of "this form" is a continuous linear functional. So I think people usually state and think of the Riesz theorem as an iff statement.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify it, I shall restate the theorem:

Suppose $f$ is a continuous linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$. Then there is a unique $y\in H$ such that
$$
f(x) = (x,y)
$$
for any $x\in H$.

$(x,y)$ denotes the inner product of $x$ and $y$, which you probably recognize as $\langle y|x \rangle$.

Note that for any fixed $y\in H$, the mapping $f:H \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(x) = (x,y)$ is a continuous linear functional.

By the way, since it's not mentioned in your book, I want to point out that linear functionals on an infinite-dimensional space $H$ do not have to be continuous. The dual space of $H$ consists of only the continuous ones.